# How to remove player after contact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.bullet.rawValue != 0)) {
        if let enemy = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
           let bullet = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
              bulletCollidedWithEnemy(bulletNode: bullet, enemyNode: enemy)
            }
    }
    
    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.player.rawValue != 0)) {
        if let enemy = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
           let player = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
              enemyCollidedWithPlayer(enemyNode: enemy, playerNode: player)
        }
    }
 }
```

My enemy and bullet both get removed after contact and update my score but my player isnt. I dont know if that last bit of code with player is wrong or its something else.

```
func bulletCollidedWithEnemy( bulletNode:SKSpriteNode, enemyNode:SKSpriteNode) {
    bulletNode.removeFromParent();
    enemyNode.removeFromParent();
    score += 1;
}
        
func enemyCollidedWithPlayer( enemyNode:SKSpriteNode, playerNode:SKNode) {
    enemyNode.removeFromParent();
    playerNode.removeFromParent();
    self.updateHighestScore(score: self.score);
    // @todo: Better pause handling
    pause();
    score = 0;
}
```

It points to enemy and missile but I had to add the second part because i need player. Its inside didbegin so i thought this was the only way for it work. Did i write it wrong or should I just remove the whole player else if code

Comment: Where do guys named 'bulletCollidedWithEnemy' and 'enemyCollidedWithPlayer' come from?  How do you know firstBody and secondBody point to particular `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: i added the extra code which should have the player working right?

Comment: Nobody can tell.  You don't show how you define your nodes.  Why is playerNode is an SKNode object while others are SKSpriteNode objects?

Comment: I actually tried going back to SKSpriteNode but it messes up the gameplay with the player and bullet, everything gets enlarged and i cant fix it so i just went back with what works. Do you think this could be the reason why it doesnt work. Having one an SKNode and the other SKSpriteNode. Also, do you want me to show just my playerNode or my enemy as well because thats a lot of code

Comment: Also, is the last part of my code in didBegin contact correct? That could be why my player wont be removed. I just dont know how to correctly rewrite the code